# Scrapy Item not return unicode when append to dataframe?

Tags: dataframe, dictionary, unicode, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy Pipeline to get all the items to a dataframe.

The code runs well but the unicode text is not showing correctly on the output of the dataframe.

However the result in csv file exported by feed_exporter is still fine. Could you guys please advise?

Here are the code

```py
#In pipelines.py
class CrawlerPipeline(object):
    def open_spider(self, spider):
        settings = get_project_settings()
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(columns=settings.get('FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS'))
        print('SUCCESS CREATE DATAFRAME', self.df.columns)


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.df = self.df.append([dict(item)]) #I think it has problem in this line of code
        print('SUCCESS APPEND RECORD TO DATAFRAME, DF LEN:', len(self.df))
        return item

#In spider.py
def parse_detail_page(self, response):
    ads = CrawlerItem()
    ads['body'] = (response.css('#sgg > div > div>  div.car_des > div::text').extract_first() or "").encode('utf-8').strip()
    yield(ads)
```

This is the incorrect output of the scraped text:

b'Salon \xc3\xb4 t\xc3\xb4 \xc3\x81nh L\xc3\xbd b\xc3\xa1n xe Kia Carens s\xe1\xba\xa3n xu\xe1\xba\xa5t 2015 m\xc3\xa0u c\xc3\xa1t'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *incorrect* output you mention is the UTF-8-encoded bytes string corresponding to the desired text string.

You have two options:

- Remove `.encode('utf-8')` from your code.
- Add `.decode('utf-8')` when reading the string from the dataframe.